# Correct complementary feedback pair output stage with multiple devices

Tags: amplifier, audio

I have a doubt about the connection of 0.1-0.47 ohm power resistors in the power stages of an amplifier.

Assuming that the CFP (complementary feedback pair) stage has multiple devices that share the output current, in what configuration should the power resistors be placed?

[image]

Another question: are power resistors in a CFP power stage necessary?

Comment: Your circuit is more like a complementary feedback trio. Whether they are necessary depends on the application, the load and the bigger picture and any requirements for short circuit protection, none of which you have made available in your question.

Comment: In power applications, the current sharing resistors are necessary to prevent thermal runaway. Thus only your last version is correct and should be used. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77045/transistors-in-parallel

Comment: @G36 can you explain why the last should be used and not the third?

Comment: You need to add these resistors (at Q1 and Q2 emitter) to be able to set the output stage quiescent current and to provide some additional thermal stability. Because for sure Q1 and Q1 will not be well matched due to the fact that Q1 is npn type and Q2 is pnp. So you should expect a 0.1V difference in Vbe voltage between two BJTs of a different type.