# Implementing a 5 Watt, Linear Variable DC Power Supply that DOESN'T get burning hot?

Tags: power-supply, driver, heat, thermal, fan

The load I am trying to drive is a fan *module* that includes a DC cooling fan, a tachometer, some status LEDs and other temperature monitoring electronics. Historically users have swapped power supplies from 5V to 12V to get different speeds, so the goal is to build something integrated to tune fan speed.

The relevant requirements are:

- Max voltage of 13.8V, min voltage of 3.3V (electronics in module become unhappy under 3.3V)
- Input must be DC, ie. no PWM. PWM makes the other electronics behave incorrectly, but the fan itself is fine.
- "High Side" control, interrupting ground path causes the other electronics to again behave badly.
- The entire module will consume up to ~5W of power at full tilt.

What I've tried:

- Small Op-Amp (LM358P) and large 20W Darlington Transistor (MJD122-1) as a current amplifier.
- Power Op-Amp (NCV0372).
- Another Power Op-Amp (L272D).

The central issue is that each of these approaches produces way too much heat! L272D has a thermal resistance (J-A) of 100 Degrees C / Watt, so very quickly the whole driver becomes screaming hot.

I have also read the great post from this board "[Transistors in parallel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77045/transistors-in-parallel)" and have tried implementing the circuit. This was much better heat-wise, but the low side switching proposed here caused the other electronics in the module to malfunction.

I feel as though there is some basic principal I'm missing here, any suggestions?

Comment: There are these old fashioned things called "heat sinks" that you should be using.  You mount your big ol' transistor on a huge chunk of metal with fins.  The metal conducts the heat away from the transistor, the fins radiate the heat away.  It is big and heavy, but it will keep your transistor from burning up.  The transistor itself doesn't get hot if the heat sink is big enough.

Comment: Also consider a DC fan with PWM/speed input.  Then no regulator is needed at all - just a fan control signal.

Comment: If you use a linear regulator, it's going to heat up. There's no way around that.

Comment: To reduce the heat there is possible to use a multi-voltage power source (more sources in series) using tapped transformer, switch them according desired output voltage and regulate the rest only.

Comment: Welcome to electronics SE! In the future, I suggest giving a schematic of what you're trying to do. I couldn't figure out exactly what you were trying to do. However, the answer to this general question is "use a DC-DC" converter as answered below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any purely resistive dropping of voltage, i.e. a linear solution, is going to cause you heating issues, as the dissipated energy has to go somewhere.

If PWM is out, you need an adjustable switching PSU, which will contain inductors to smooth out the discontinuous input current into a lower voltage smooth output current.

You state 5W maximum, but not what voltage that is at, so hard to work out for certain the maximum current requirement.  Assuming there is a fairly proportional change of current with voltage, you probably only need a 500mA supply, and there are a fair number of adjustable voltage DC-DC converters that would fit your application, for instance [this](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/RPX-0.5Q.pdf) Recom unit shown on the Farnell website.

Digital control of the DC-DC converter can be achieved via the use of a DAC to inject/remove current from the FB node.  This [app note](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/digital-adjustment-of-dcdc-converter-output-voltage-in-portable-applications.htm) from Analog Devices has an example circuit.

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick reply. So using one of these converters, the way we would achieve variable output would be to use a potentiometer or a digital potentiometer to set the input divider and therefor modify the output voltage?

Comment: Yes, that's typically how you design adjustable control loops (generally, not just regulated voltage supplies), by scaling the feedback

Comment: Some care required with the digital pot, but yes, the concept is valid, and a traditional pot would definitely work.

Comment: There are also control approaches where you use a DAC and an additional resistor to inject (or remove) current from the FB node, and adjust the equilibrium voltage.

Comment: You can also inject a current into the feedback pin through a resistor from a DAC to control the output voltage. It would be in parallel with R4 in the schematic of the part that was linked to.

Comment: @TimWescott, I would love to see an example circuit that implements digital control of one of these switching power supplies.

Comment: I've added a link to an app note showing the DAC control.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, any linear supply will be forced to burn up power and make heat.

In electronics usage, a "linear supply" operates by having a pass element, usually a transistor, that takes the same amount of current *in* as it delivers *to* the load.  The pass element implements a voltage drop -- it is the current, across that voltage drop, that generates heat.

Most switching supplies use the same basic feedback structure, where they have a feedback pin (usually labeled "FB"), and they hold that pin to a fixed voltage.

As an example, the [part that @colintd mentioned](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/RPX-0.5Q.pdf) will try to hold it's FB pin to \$0.807\mathrm V\$ (see the section "OUTPUT VOLTAGE TRIMMING" in the data sheet).

[image: Application schematic of RPX-0.5Q]

For a fixed voltage, you go with the above schematic.  For a variable voltage, you put in a DAC, and a resistor from the DAC output to the FB pin.  I'm going to call that resistor R5.

The voltage at the FB pin will be equal to
$$V_{FB} = \frac{\frac {V_{out}}{R_3} + \frac{V_{DAC}}{R_5}}{\frac{1}{R_3} + \frac{1}{R_4} + \frac{1}{R_5}} = \frac{R_4 R_5 V_{out} + R_3 R_4 V_{DAC}}{R_4 R_5 + R_3 R_5 + R_4 R_5} \tag 1$$

Note that because the voltages in the numerator sum, the *highest* output voltage will be when \$V_{DAC}\$ is *lowest*.  This is just inherent in using this scheme; pay attention because most DACs will come out of reset with \$V_{DAC} = 0\mathrm V\$, commanding the highest-possible output voltage.

The chip will adjust \$V_{OUT}\$ until \$V_{FB} = 0.807\mathrm V\$, unless it can't (for instance, it appears to be a buck converter, so you can't have \$V_{OUT} > V_{IN}\$).

If you pick a high and low \$V_{OUT}\$, and a high and low \$V_{DAC}\$, then you can plug those into (1).  If you choose a value for one resistor (i.e., \$75 \mathrm k \Omega\$ for R3) then you'll have two equations, with \$R4\$ and \$R5\$ as unknowns.  Solve for those values, find the nearest standard values that will fit, check that your circuit will make you happy, and you're ready to roll.

Comment: Excellent point about startup. There are a number of DACs with internal eeproms which will save the last value, and which may be a good match for this application

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which parts of the question are describing the fan, and which are describing the input to the system.

IF the max DC input voltage from some unknown external power supply is 13.8 V

AND IF the maximum power consumed by the fan at max voltage is 5 W

THEN the max. fan current is 363 mA.

For an all-linear solution, why not use an LM317?  It can handle 5 times the current, the output is adjustable to less than the min. req. 3.3 V so it has the range, and its adjustment resistor is referenced to GND.  (Some digi-pots like that.)

The worst case voltage across the regulator is 10.5 V.  A BLDC fan motor's current draw is not a constant; it decreases with a decrease in fan voltage, but not linearly.  If we assume the current (at 3.3 V) decreases by only 50% (a very worst-case assumption), that is 180 mA through a regulator with 10.5 V across it, or just under 2 W of heat in the LM317 to be removed.  A TO-220 device can survive that with no heatsink, but it will get very hot.  If the regulator is anywhere near the fan's exhaust stream, a fairly small heatsink would be adequate.